# How to save text buffer to file using Python and gtk?

Tags: python, gtk

I am trying to create a text editor for Ubuntu (going to give it a try!) using gtk2 and python.
So far I have been able to implement the open function.  However I just don't know how I can get the contents of the TextView and write them into a file (the user would have named and decided which directory to save it in).

Here is the code for the gtk.FileChooserDialog save function:

```
def on_saveButton_clicked(widget):
        print 'saveButton clicked'
        savechooser = gtk.FileChooserDialog(title='Save File', action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE, 
                                                        buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                                        gtk.STOCK_SAVE, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
        filter = gtk.FileFilter()
        filter.set_name('All files')
        filter.add_pattern('*')
        savechooser.add_filter(filter)

        pyFilter = gtk.FileFilter()
        pyFilter.set_name('Python source file')
        pyFilter.add_pattern('*.py')
        savechooser.add_filter(pyFilter)

        rbFilter = gtk.FileFilter()
        rbFilter.set_name('Ruby source file')
        rbFilter.add_pattern('*.rb')
        savechooser.add_filter(rbFilter)

        cppFilter = gtk.FileFilter()
        cppFilter.set_name('C++ source file')
        cppFilter.add_pattern('*.cpp')
        savechooser.add_filter(cppFilter)

        response = savechooser.run()
        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            filename = savechooser.get_filename()
            print filename, 'selected.'
        elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
            print 'Closed, file not saved.'
        savechooser.destroy()
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'd start this kind of project by using GTK3 instead, look at this tutorial for example: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/textview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, consider updating your code to Python 3 and Gtk+3 (PyGObject) as @SylvainPineau suggests. Then, you need to make the GtkTextView an instance property/member so you can access it from within `on_saveButton_clicked`. Lastly, to actually save the contents of the GtkTextBuffer you can use Python builtin functions or GIO.

With Python builtin functions (and assuming you save the GtkTextView in `self.view`):

```
if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
    filename = savechooser.get_filename()
    print(filename, 'selected.')

    buf = self.view.get_buffer()
    text = buf.get_text(buf.get_start_iter(),
                        buf.get_end_iter(),
                        True)
    try:
        open(filename, 'w').write(text)
    except SomeError as err:
        print('Could not save %s: %s' % (filename, err))
```

**PS:** I notice you are not using classes, since your `on_saveButton_clicked` function doesn't have the `self` argument. If so, for the sake of testing your current code you can make `self.view` into a `TEXT_VIEW` global variable.

Comment: Why would I need to use Gtk+3?

Comment: I'm using gtksourceview2.

Comment: @Abunujum, well, you don't _have_ to use Gtk+3. It's recommended nonetheless, that way your application will be able to take advantage of the new features, improvements and bug fixes :)

Comment: Yes ... that may be a better idea, it will be useful in the long run I suppose.

Comment: What is the 'w' parameter for?

Comment: In that line, I am creating a file object with write mode (because I am going to write to the file). In general, in the Python interpreter you can type `help(thing)` to get help about `thing`. Try running `python` in a terminal, then execute `help(open)` to check it out.